# Example of a REST service implemented in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rest

Is there a good sample of an REST service implemented in ASP.NET MVC that demonstrates the best practices and easy to understand for a beginner?

Comment: You're question is very broad. Try narrowing it down by telling us what you've tried so far (and if you haven't tried anything yet, I would suggest trying to code something first and then coming back and asking a question).

Comment: Have you looked at openrasta for ideas?

Comment: I tried to rewrote the body of the question, but I cannot really narrow it down. I need some sort of reference implementation of a rest service in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is not really clear to me it seems you want some sort of REST based API?

Here's an example returning json or xml: http://omaralzabir.com/create_rest_api_using_asp_net_mvc_that_speaks_both_json_and_plain_xml/

Comment: @vdcrijsen Thanks for the link. It seems to be just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.beletsky.net/2011/01/implementation-of-rest-service-with.html

https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/rest.mvc.example

I think It will help you.